# How to add title, snippet and icon to ClusterItem?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, clickable, markerclusterer

I had this activity:

```
public class MapViewer extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Database db = new Database(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapviewer);

        try {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

                this.addMerchantMarkers(new MarkerOptions());
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addMerchantMarkers(MarkerOptions mo) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor result = dbRead.rawQuery("SELECT title, addr, lat, lon FROM users", null);

        while(result.moveToNext()) {            
            map.addMarker(mo.position(new LatLng(result.getFloat(2), result.getFloat(3)))
                    .title(result.getString(0))
                    .snippet(result.getString(1))
                    );;
        }
    }
}
```

that i changed in the following way to use markers clustering:

```
public class MapViewer extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Database db = new Database(this);
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapviewer);

        try {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

                setUpClusterer();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpClusterer() {
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, map);

        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        addItems();
    }

    private void addItems() {
        SQLiteDatabase dbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor result = dbRead.rawQuery("SELECT lat, lon, title, addr FROM users", null);

        while(result.moveToNext()) {
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(result.getFloat(0), result.getFloat(1));
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i don't know how to add title, snippet and icon to every marker like previous code.
Now if i click on single marker nothing happens...
How to get that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here you should work with ClusterManager itself.
For example, setting on cluster item click:

```
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
                //put your code here
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And there are other different methods in ClusterManager class.
You'll need a less obvious code to assign info window to marker or cluster - you should use this code:

```
mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(new ClusterInfoWindow());
```

There MarkerInfoWindowAdapter and ClusterWindowAdapter is your classes, which implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.

With icons it's a little harder, because clustering changes icons to default. You should use method:

```
public void setRenderer(com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.ClusterRenderer<T> view)
```

You could your own renderer class and override some methods. For example, to set custom icons use such a class:

```
class OwnIconRendered extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public OwnIconRendered(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                           ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(item.getIcon());
        markerOptions.snippet(item.getSnippet());
        markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }
}
```

And use it in such way:

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new OwnIconRendered(activity.getApplicationContext(), getMap(), mClusterManager));
```

Comment: Nevermind about icon. Do you have some examples that show how to add title and snippet to markers that are inside clusters?

Comment: You can add title and snippet in the same way as icon - in method onBeforeClusterRendered (see answer) use methods title(String title) and snippet(String snippet) of markerOptions object.

Comment: the second option works perfectly and easy to implement. thanks ;)

Comment: Hi, I have 3 icons with 3 types, How I can change in "OwnIconRendered" about type ?

Comment: How to change the cluster image instead of marker image ?