# How do I change the icons for the cluster objects in java google maps

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, icons, markerclusterer

I'm stuck with a little problem in the Clustering library for google maps in Android studio.
The problem is that I only have the default icons for the cluster objects, like [these icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOdUa.png).

I would like to give the markers a custom icon, but I cant find anything about it on internet. And I find it too unclear on the [library page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: go to below of the page you referred. You will find the solution

Comment: Here is a very good solution for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443749/how-do-i-change-the-icons-for-the-cluster-objects-in-java-google-maps

Comment: @Shivo The link directed to my question

Comment: sorry for that, here is the Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745299/how-to-add-title-snippet-and-icon-to-clusteritem/27745681#27745681

Comment: Thanks @Shivo, but I've tried that and it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! Here it is:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions)
{

    final Drawable clusterIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.context,R.drawable.[your_icon]);

    mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(clusterIcon);

    //modify padding for one or two digit numbers
    if (cluster.getSize() < 10) {
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(40, 20, 0, 0);
    }
    else 
    {
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(30, 20, 0, 0);
    }

    Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));

}
```

This worked for me.